# How to give my database to a friend for duplication in a secure way

Tags: export

We have developed a website for a single franchise of an organization. Another franchise has contacted us and asked us if they can have a copy of our work to save time. We are happy to help them.

I have created an archive of our theme and plugins, and a short explanation of how everything fits together.

I also would like to give them a copy of our database, so they can have a full copy of our site to start from. (I know they will have to use a [smart database search and replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to fix the urls).

However, I am concerned about sharing our full database. I assume it contains administrative credential information and other data that should not be shared over an open network.

How can I export our page structure and embedded image data to include with the rest of the site's files, without also including information that should remain secret?

Comment: What information needs to remain secret? Just the user data (user details inc. password etc.)? Or is there other confidential/secret data that should be considered?

Comment: @Matthew: The only item I can think of are the administrative accounts and their passwords. There is nothing else on the site that is private. Of course, there may be additional items in the WP database that are generally considered sensitive that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joshua - thanks for replying to my question and confirming what needs to remain confidential. If there's nothing specific you can think of other than admin user data that needs to remain confidential, then I would be confident in saying that's all you need to worry about (unless you have any plugins which have usernames/passwords, or similar set in their settings).

What I would recommend to achieve this is to create a new admin user for the user at the franchise from within your WordPress admin, then do a full database export from your hosting control panels/cPanel's phpMyAdmin.

Once you have the SQL file downloaded, simply edit the file in a text editor and remove the lines from the `wp_users` table that correspond to your own admin users, leaving the new franchise admin user in place.

Once this is done, delete the franchise user from your WordPress admin area and then send them the modified SQL export file.

The only other sensitive thing would be your sites `wp-config.php` file as this will contain your database connection details (server, username, password).

Comment: this does not seem entirely safe to me, apart form `wp_users` there is also `wp_usermeta` table that might contain sensitive data related to users (any kind of custom options not included in `wp_users` table).
Also, by manually deleting data from `wp_users` you keep the relationship to nonexistant users in `wp_posts` table:
https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/25/WP4.4.2-ERD.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that would cover all your needs, but it seems that you could simply use the built in wordpress export tool ( 'http://yoursite/wp-admin/export.php' )

You can select only the post types that are needed to reproduce the structure of your website and also narrow the export to selected dates and status. Media is also there as a post type available for export.

Also, since you're getting an XML file as a result, it's quite easy to perform search and replace on the sensitive data (the file would contain each post's author - user ID and user email - you could change that to fake user data.  During the import WordPress will try to create the user or assign posts to existing one).

Comment: OP has asked how to do a full copy of the site, not just the content...